# Elastic Search: URI Search is inaccurate

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am searching via Webbrowser Firefox with the following URI:

> http://localhost:9200/xyz-leads/lead/_search?q=datetimeHour:22_09_2015__12&&deliveryType:EMAIL

But I only get hits with deliveryType:RVS, not EMAIL.

If I search for deliveryType:RVS I get 3 hits.

I know there are 3 results for RVS and 0 for EMAIL with the datetimeHour above, in total.

I guess the standard behaviour of ElasticSearch is, that it ignores the second search value 'deliveryType' and uses only the first 'datetimeHour' if there are no results for both.

If I search for deliveryType:Email, then I want no hits in the response.

Do I need to set some additional ElasticSearch parameters?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html

```
_source: {
country: "DEU",
brand: "A",
leadGroup: "TEST",
leadID: 108798,
deliveryType: "RVS",
datetime: 1442916913000,
datetimeFormatted: "22.09.2015 12:15:13",
datetimeHour: "22_09_2015__12",
datetimeDay: "22_09_2015"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query string query you stuff into your URL (i.e. in the `q=...` parameter) needs to be well-formed according to the [query string query syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html?q=query%20string%20quer#query-string-syntax)

Try this instead (i.e. using `AND` instead of `&&`)

```
http://localhost:9200/xyz-leads/lead/_search?q=datetimeHour:22_09_2015__12%20AND%20deliveryType:EMAIL
```